# Hey! Where did my edits go?

Tags: bug

I cleaned up the rather sloppy but well-intentioned edit by a new user at https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/26496/revisions, and submitted that (leaving the "original edit was helpful" box checked. But now I just see the original messy edit. What happened to my work?

I was doing this on an iPhone (with the full site) and the UI is a bit iffy there, but it all seemed to go through.

Comment: *What* went missing?

Comment: I removed the added square brackets, and as a bonus I fixed Matt's (usual; heh) _it's for its_ error.

Comment: Smells like a bug to me, so updated tag accordingly...